# Creating a board in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to create a board/grid on python 3.5 that looks like this:

[image]
The height/width are user inputs. 
This is what I currently have:

```
board = [['*' for i, row in enumerate(range(2))] for row in enumerate(range(3))]
for i, row in enumerate(board):
    actual_board = ' '.join(row)
    row_text = '{0} '.format(i)
    print (row_text + actual_board)
```

This outputs:

```
0 * *
1 * *
2 * *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach, slightly more verbose code.

```
def makeboard(rows, cols):
    board = []
    for r in range(rows):
        brow = []
        for c in range(cols):
            if r == c == 0:
                 brow.append(' ')
            elif r == 0:
                 brow.append(str(c-1))
            elif c == 0:
                 brow.append(str(r-1))
            else:
                 brow.append('*')
        board.append(brow)
    return board

b = makeboard(4,3)

for row in b:
    print ' '.join(row)
```

Comment: How would I make this start with 0 instead of 1?
edit: I think I figured it out. I just put -1 in str(c) -1

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `board`, you're not using `i` or `row` - there's no need to `enumerate()` a `range()`. Just use `range()`.

```
board = [['*' for column in range(2)] for row in range(3)]
print(' ' + ''.join(map(str, range(2)))) # print column labels
for row, item in enumerate(board): # for each row
    print(str(row) + ''.join(item)) # print the row label and contents
```

Result:

```
 01
0**
1**
2**
```